Flutter : Build Error during 'flutter build apk'
Whenever i try to build the apk, this error always shows
`../AndroidDependencies/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_archive-4.2.0/lib/flutter_archive.dart:190:44: Error: The getter 'name' isn't defined for the class 'ZipFileOperation'.
 - 'ZipFileOperation' is from 'package:flutter_archive/flutter_archive.dart' ('../AndroidDependencies/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_archive-4.2.0/lib/flutter_archive.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'name'.
        return Future<String>.value(result.name);
                                           ^^^^

or this one
e: C:\Development\AndroidDependencies\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\arcore_flutter_plugin-0.0.11\android\src\main\kotlin\com\difrancescogianmarco\arcore_flutter_plugin\ArCoreView.kt: (245, 38): Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onActivityCreated(@NonNull p0: Activity, @Nullable p1: Bundle?): Unit defined in android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks
e: C:\Development\AndroidDependencies\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\arcore_flutter_plugin-0.0.11\android\src\main\kotlin\com\difrancescogianmarco\arcore_flutter_plugin\ArCoreView.kt: (246, 13): 'onActivityCreated' overrides nothing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script 'C:\Development\AndroidDependencies\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.



Process 'command 'C:\Development\AndroidDependencies\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

This is my pubsec.yaml
name: project
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_cube: ^0.0.6
  ar_flutter_plugin: ^0.6.2
  path_provider: ^2.0.4
  flutter_archive: ^4.1.1
  url_launcher: ^6.0.10
  arcore_flutter_plugin: ^0.0.11
  model_viewer: ^0.8.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
     - images/
     - model/
     - assets/
     - assets/jet/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages


This is the code that's related to flutter_archive
Future<void> _downloadAndUnpack(String url, String filename) async {
    var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    var response = await request.close();
    var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
    String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    File file = new File('$dir/$filename');
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    print("Downloading finished, path: " + '$dir/$filename');

    // To print all files in the directory: print(Directory(dir).listSync());
    try {
      await ZipFile.extractToDirectory(
          zipFile: File('$dir/$filename'), destinationDir: Directory(dir));
      print("Unzipping successful");
    } catch (e) {
      print("Unzipping failed: " + e);
    }
  }

is there anyway me for me to fix this, thankyou.

It look like a conflict with flutter_archive version: ^4.1.1 vs 4.2.0
Try to:

remove pubspec.lock
flutter clean
flutter pub get

